# Move Rails 4 translations to PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, translation, rails-i18n

I need to store locales of Rails app in DB. And give access for admin to edit locales from admin area of app (activeadmin).

This is idea what I have.

1. Create file with locales named, e.g. en.yml.lock.
2. Write translations in this file (duplicate to en.yml in development).
3. Create table for translations (json or hstore).
4. Create Capistrano task and load file to DB.
5. After deploy generate en.yml on server with values from DB.
6. After editing translations in DB click some button "Regenerate" or use some callback and rewrite en.yml on server.
7. Reboot application.

What are you think about it? May you have more pretty solution?

And one more question. I think storing this with JSON is easier, but how can I generate form for translation in which user can edit only values, not keys?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record ?

Comment: @zwippie Yes. I looked at it. But I have 2 doubts. 1: It looks old and does not support. 2: I have many translations and afraid of heavy SQL queries to my DB. I think that yml file should be much faster. But I could be wrong